# ngrx: Effect for store INIT action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I want to dispatch an action when ngrx store inits (`@ngrx/store/init`). I created an Effect for that:

```
    @Effect()
  reloadConext$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(INIT),
    switchMap(() => {
      console.log('INIT ACTION');
        //dispatch my action here
        return of([]);
    }
```

The effect is not being fired when store init action is dispatched. I have effects modules for root registered in app.module :

```
EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffects]),
```

If I remove the `ofType` action filter the event is fired. Does anyone know what the filter for init action is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#root_effects_init) or the [onInitEffects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#controlling-effects) lifecycle method for non root effects.

ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT from the docs:

```
@Effect()
init$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
  map(action => ...)
);
```

onInitEffects from the docs:

```
class UserEffects implements OnInitEffects {
  ngrxOnInitEffects(): Action {
    return { type: '[UserEffects]: Init' };
  }
}
```

Comment: if anyone comes to this and needs `@ngrx/store/init` instead for some reason, you can get that from `import { INIT } from '@ngrx/store';`

Comment: Thank you very for that tips, I was trying INIT and INITIAL_STATE with no success.